# How to manipulate An array of random alphabet letters?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of size 1000 that holds upper case letters and lower case letters of the entire alphabet.

How would i print the total number of lower case letters generated 
and the total number of upper case letters generated?

ALSO

A count of how many of each letter were generated (showing the letter and how many were generated) as well as the percent of the total that letter represents.

Comment: compare the each character using ASCII values

Comment: smells like homework

Comment: What did you try so far to achive this result? if you have anything, post it and tell us where you are stuck. Otherwise don´t except to get an answer since it does not meet the SO Question rules

Comment: Sounds like class or interview task. At least split it into two questions. At least post what did you try already

Comment: im trying to figure out how to use the array im working on

Comment: so far i have filled my array entirely by using rand and the ascii table of a-z

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int lower = 0;
int upper = 0;
Map<Character, Integer> letterCounter = new TreeMap<>();

for (char letter : letterArr) { //Might need to use String if letterArr is String[]
   if (Character.isLowerCase(letter)) lower++;
   if (Character.isUpperCase(letter)) upper++;
   Integer count = letterCounter.get(letter);
   if (count != null) count++;
   else letterCounter.put(letter, new Integer(1));
}

System.out.println("Number of upper case letters: " + upper);
System.out.println("Number of lower case letters: " + lower);

for (Map.entry<Character, Integer> e : letterCounter.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println("Number of " + e.getKey() + " = " + e.getValue());
}
```